# Can't get babel and amsthm to play nice once Hebrew is loaded

Tags: memoir, babel, amsthm, hebrew

I am working in LaTeX, and I am trying to get babel and amsthm to play nice together.

I produced a minimal example (which gives a different error than the full project, but getting this to work could be the stepping stone I need for success in that)

```
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{memoir}  
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{babel}  
\selectlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]  
\begin{document}  
\chapter{Hello}  
This is some text.\newline  
\begin{theorem}  
This is a theorem.  
\end{theorem}  
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}   
שלום  
\end{otherlanguage}  
\hfill\newline  
English again!  
\end{document}
```

This does not compile. It would compile if:

1. I comment out the `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` part,
2. I remove the use of babel completely, or
3. I simply remove the Hebrew from loading (and comment out the relevant part).

The error message is:

```
! Missing { inserted.  
<to be read again>   
                   T  
l.14 T  
      his is a theorem.  
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.  
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections  
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.  
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)
```

This error is pointed at the `\begin{theorem}` part and there is another which seems to be related to the `\end{theorem}` line, it's slightly different:

```
)  
Runaway text?  
This is a theorem. \end {theorem} \begin {otherlanguage}{hebrew} \\ש\ETC.  
! File ended while scanning text of \dth@everypar.  
<inserted text>   
                }  
<*> babeltest.tex  

I suspect you have forgotten a \`}', causing me  
to read past where you wanted me to stop.  
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,  
you'd better type \`E' or \`X' now and fix your file.  

! Emergency stop.
```

For the purpose of the project I don't need any theorems to be stated in Hebrew. I just need some text and minor mathematical symbols, these will be appended to the end of the document, too.

Is there a way to make `babel` ignore `amsthm` each other, so that I can have one big project for everything, or do I need to create a separate project for the Hebrew part?

**Edit:**

It seems that the main problem with my big project is the fact that I define a long list of `\newtheorem` and counters (using `aliascnt`) and I think that `babel` is just getting confused by all those new counters and theorem styles.

Any information on what and how to correct this would be mighty useful as well!

**Edit II:**

I just noticed that when only removing the `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}` lines it compiles without errors, but the "**Chapter 1**" is gone. I am also adding the [memoir] tag because I think it might be an internal clash between `babel` and `memoir`.

---

P.S.

It doesn't work if I change the class from `memoir` to something else. I just use memoir in my main project so I figured it would be best to keep it here as well.

Comment: I suggest you switch your example to use the 'article' (or 'minimal') documentclass, so as not to complicate things with 'memoir' (which doesn't have much to do with the fundamental issue). [Here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/5640) are more general guidelines to writing a Minimal Working Example. Also, `aliascnt` is not the problem: aliascnt + babel + Hebrew work fine (sort of) with `ntheorem` instead of amsthm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known and painful problem: `rlbabel.def` redefines
`\everypar`, which is used by `amsthm`.

Here's a flakey workaround (not a minimal workaround - I'm basing this on @WD40's not-so-MWE):

```
\documentclass[hebrew,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\let\everypar\o@everypar
\makeatother
\selectlanguage{english}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
This is some text.\newline
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
שלום
\end{otherlanguage}
\hfill\newline
English again!
\end{document}
```

(`\o@everypar` is the command that `rlbabel.def` stores as an alias of the original `\everypar`.) This might interfere with `amsthm`s operation.

PS:

- The problem indeed has not much to do with the memoir class.
- This workaround was communicated to me in 2006 by Enrico Gregorio.

Comment: Hah, it works! Now `babel` throws `hyperref` off course by adding all sort of `\beginL` to things, is there a way to fix that too?

Comment: Also, it breaks the custom chapter headers for some reason. So there *is* a minor clash with `memoir`.

Comment: @WD40: First of all, I do suggest you switch to `ntheorem` or `thmtools`; you won't get very far in life with Hebrew + `amsthm` + `hyperref`. Other than that, ask a new TeX.SX question...

Answer (score 1):

`amsthm` and `babel` with the `hebrew` option just don't work together. If I recall correctly it's because they both define a `\R` macro. You'll probably have more luck switching to `xelatex` and using the `polyglossia` package.

Comment: How painful is the move from `pdflatex` to `xelatex`?

Comment: Also, is there a way to simply make `amsthm` unload and load `babel` at the end of the current document?

Comment: @WD40: Can be somewhat painful. There are all sorts of bustage (although it's not Vafa's fault.)

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: I see. I suppose I'll do my next multilingual project in XeTeX from the start.