# Remove parentheses from theorem without amsthm package

Tags: theorems

I would like to remove the parentheses from the newtheorem I define. The thing is I cannot use amsthm (it collides with another package, babel, as I understand). Is there a possibility to remove these without the extra package?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}

\newtheorem{theo}{theor}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Some sentence]
1234
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

This code does not compile unless I comment one of the `\usepackage` statements.

The parentheses in question are shown here, in the result for this MWE, when I comment out the `usepackage{babel}`:

[image]

Comment: please add a complete example code that show the problem

Comment: What parentheses are you referring to?

Comment: I added a full example. I'm referring to the parentheses I get when I add a name to the theorem. The question is can I remove them without using ``amsthm``.

Comment: Concerning the interaction between `babel` and `amsthm` you can give a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66375)

Comment: @campa , thank you. I tried these solutions but I then I get other problems related to what babel should do (inverted order of characters, etc.). That's why I'm looking for some solution that uses the original package, ``theorem``, that I know works in this case.

Comment: You can try with the following and see this is what you actually want: 
`\makeatletter
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist\item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ #3}]\itshape} \makeatother`

Comment: Why do you want to remove the prentheses? That seems very unnatural. What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: I would like to replace them with inverted parehtheses. In RTL languages the parentheses are not displayed correctly.

Comment: @SunilkumarKS , that did not do anything. Does it work with ``\usepackage{theorem}``?

Comment: Nope!  Here is my code to obtain the result:

`\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
  \item[\hskip 
  \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ #3}]\itshape}

\newtheorem{theo}{theor}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}[Some sentence]
1234
\end{theo}

\end{document}`

Comment: The weird situation I'm in requires I use ``theorem`` but not ``amsthm``. But as I wrote in the full answer, I used your idea and got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @SunilkumarKS's response I managed to do that by locating the definition in the original `sty` file (`thp.sty`)

I just add this, which is a copy of the contents of the sty file, only without the parentheses around ##3.

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\th@plain{\normalfont\itshape
  \def\@begintheorem##1##2{%
        \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2]}%
\def\@opargbegintheorem##1##2##3{%
   \item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ ##3]}}
\makeatother
```

Thank you!