# Why does the “lifted” ntheorem proof environment sometimes fail to add the QED symbol?

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

Reading:

[ntheorem with the [amsthm] option ignores styling of a theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30262/5640)

I adopted the suggested proof environment for `ntheorem` without the `amsmath` option. I also made sure to add the `thmmarks` options to `ntheorem`, to enable end-of-theorem/end-of-proof marks. However - if I write this document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \blacksquare
\usepackage{mathtools}

 \newcommand{\proofname}{Proof}
 \newcounter{proof}\newcounter{currproofctr}\newcounter{endproofctr}%
 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \th@nonumberplain
  \def\theorem@headerfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont
  \@thm{proof}{proof}{{#1}.}}%
   {\@endtheorem} % and this ends the definition of the proof environment

\newcommand\proofSymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
\qedsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 1.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 2.
    \begin{align*}
    42        
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

and some text afterwards.

\end{document}
```

I [get](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hydhgjrqrszb) a black square on the first proof, but not the second. Why is that?

Comment: @Marijn : Sorry for yanking your chain, my earlier question was kind of stupid, this is the more serious problem (I just deleted too much when trying to create a minimal example).

Comment: Also for this one the `\openbox` part is not used I think? You redefine `\proofSymbol` at the end of the preamble, which discards the earlier `\gdef`. That is not the core issue of course (the output is the same after deleting the `\openbox` definition).

Comment: Just out of idle curosity: Do you have a specific reason for employing the `ntheorem` package rather than the `amsthm` package? The reason I ask is that the latter package defines a very handy `proof` environment and even provides the macro `\qedhere` to place the QED symbol in some other location than at the very end.

Comment: @Mico: [This reason](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30262/5640). Although things may have changed over time.

Comment: Note that the issue does not seem related to your custom `\newenvironment{proof}`, with a regular `\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\newtheorem{myproof}{Proof}` you see the same behavior (first proof with square, second without square). The `ntheorem` manual mentions (although not very clearly) that for theorems ending with math you need `amsthm` for end marks (page 15), so it you want to use this without `amsthm` then you probably need to lift some code from that package as well.

Comment: @Marijn: Dropped the `\openbox`. Do you have any idea what code specifically I would need to lift, or shall I just dig into that to look?

Comment: @einpoklum From a quick look in the source `amsthm` uses over 150 lines of code for just the QED symbol, so I gues the other way around (i.e., make `ntheorem` with the `amsthm` option respect formatting modifications) would be easier to do.

Comment: @Marijn: But `amsthm` may be [problematic for use with Hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66375/5640).

Comment: @einpoklum that sounds like a different problem, maybe some solution can be found there as well - however modifying the theorem style does seem to be compatible with `amsthm`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the regular interface works as expected (after compiling two times), including modified formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \blacksquare
\usepackage{mathtools}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 1.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog 2.
    \begin{align*}
    42        
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

and some text afterwards.

\end{document}
```

[image]